# Change in work done is or is not equal to the change in potential energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, potential-energy

what is potential energy?  is it the work done by external forces or internal forces on a body? i searched on the net and it said the the negative of the work done by conservative forces is potential energy.  not only that it also said that no energy left or entered the system where there was only potential energy.  how is it possible?  my textbook on electrostatic forces says that if a test charge is moved without changing the kinetic energy in a constant electric field then the work done according to work energy theorem is 0.  then does that mean the change in potential energy is not equal to work done. i m so confused please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Potential energy is **just *stored* energy**. That's all you need to know.
- Work is ***added* or *spent* energy**. Another quantity that can happen to equal potential energy stored. But not always; only if no energy is lost on the way. They are two different quantities.

Potential energy happens to be "*the negative of the work done by conservative forces*", and this *is* how you can store potential energy, yes. But don't confuse the two; have a look at this example:

- While a ball lies on a shelf, there is potential energy stored. No work is being done at this moment.
- Work *was* done in order to get the ball up there. You need to the add energy (in the form of work for example) which you want to store.
- Work *will* be done when you "release" this system - meaning, when you let the ball fall down. Then gravity is doing work on the ball, sucking out the energy there was stored in the ball/Earth system.

This is why you can read that work done by *conservative* forces equals the potential energy they can store. Because for a conservative force, none of the energy is "lost"; it is all stored.

Work done **by conservative forces** and potential energy can therefore be thought of as equivalent and equal. But keep them seperated in your thinking as different terms and different physical quantities.

Comment: i understood clearly what u meant to say.  let me repeat it nd please correct me if I am wrong. potential energy is the energy which is present in a body due to its location. be it a spring or a body in a gravitational field or an electrical field. change in potential energy occurs when the internal forces do work.  as a result it is the negative of the work done by external conservative forces. this is why whenever there is only potential energy present then no energy is given out or taken in.  but i still m confused about the part of change in potential energy

Comment: how can we change potential energy without changing kinetic energy?  not only that how can a change in potential energy result in no absorption or release of energy?

Comment: nd as my book says that the charge is moved without change in kinetic energy it bcoms more incomprehensible. of course if its moving then there will b a change in mechanical energy.  wudnt it b?

Comment: @EshaMukhopadhyay "*potential energy is the energy which is present in a body due to its location.*" Almost, just be careful when saying "in a body". **Elastic** potential energy in a spring is stored in the body of the spring. (Same for e.g. **chemical** potential energy.) But **gravitational** (as well as e.g. **electric** and **magnetic**) potential energy is present because two object pull in each other, so it is not stored in one of them alone. It is rather stored in the "system" or "field" between them. A small detail, maybe, but good to be aware of.

Comment: @EshaMukhopadhyay "* change in potential energy occurs when the internal forces do work.*" Yes, internal forces within the **system** (gravity is an internal force within the ball/Earth-system). "*as a result it is the negative of the work done by external conservative forces.*" Yes, and the reason is pretty obvious: the potential energy *only exists* because the conservative force (like gravity) pulls. If it didn't there would be no tendency for the object (like the ball) to move when released, and then no energy would be seen as stored.

Comment: @EshaMukhopadhyay "*this is why whenever there is only potential energy present then no energy is given out or taken in.*" Well, yes if you by "only" mean that there are no external forces. If I lift a book to a shelf, then I am doing work (corresponding to gravity doing negative work) on the book in order to add potential energy to this book/Earth-system by seperating them further.

Comment: @EshaMukhopadhyay "*how can we change potential energy without changing kinetic energy?*" When lifting a book, we do indeed change the kinetic energy *along the way*. But after moving it, it is staying still and stationary on the shelf. No change in kinetic energy from start to end position. Potential energy has not really gotten anything to do with kinetic energy - it just often happens to convert to it, when released (the ball speeds up while potential energy is reduced, when it falls from the shelf), but potential energy could also very slowly be converted into e.g. heat or work or so.

Comment: @EshaMukhopadhyay "*how can a change in potential energy result in no absorption or release of energy?*" Doesn't a book falling from a shelf release energy? Potential energy is converted into kinetic. When I'm lifting a book to a shelf, I am also doing work on it; I add energy which is then stored as potential. losing or gaining one type of energy will always come from or go to another type of energy (no energy is every created or disappearing; it is only ever converted from one type to another according to the 1st law of thermodynamics.)

Comment: @EshaMukhopadhyay "*nd as my book says that the charge is moved without change in kinetic energy it bcoms more incomprehensible. of course if its moving then there will b a change in mechanical energy. wudnt it b?*" A satellite drifting through outerspace experiences no change in any form of energy. Its kinetic energy is never changed or converted - it just continues at constant speed. Same for an electric charge. After it is speeded up, it only slows down again if an electric field pushes it to stop later on. And then that field is doing (negative) work on it. Otherwise it doesn't stop.

Comment: thanx for ur detailed explanation. i thoroughly understand it now

Comment: @EshaMukhopadhyay You are very welcome; glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia states the following:

> In physics, potential energy is energy possessed by a body by virtue of its position relative to others, stresses within itself, electric charge, and other factors.

and

> Potential energy is the stored energy of an object.

These statements need qualification.

The first thing to note is that the forces which are being considered must be **conservative** which means that the work done by such forces are path independent.

A book on a table does not of itself have gravitational potential energy.
It is the book and the Earth which have the gravitational potential energy.
In this case what this means is that if the book is dropped the book-Earth system will lose gravitational potential energy and the book **and** the Earth will gain kinetic energy.
So here you have energy stored in the book-Earth system because they were separated.
In the example with the two masses you could reason that the Earth exerts a mass on the book and the book exerts a force on the Earth.
These are two internal forces of the book-Earth system.
I know that they are internal forces because they a Newton third law pair - equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.
Each of the forces undergoes a displacement and so does work which manifests itself as an increase in the kinetic energy of the particle on which it is acting.

You could look at a similar situation where the book to Earth separation is increased by the application of two external forces.
On on the book and the other on the Earth.
Both those external two forces undergo a displacement and so do work on the book and the Earth resulting is a greater separation between the two.
The gravitational potential of the book-Earth system has been increased.

In this example the work done by the external forces is deemed to be positive because the direction of a forces and its displacement is the same.
However one could have evaluated the work done by the internal (gravitational forces) and then then work done would have been negative because as the book and Earth are being separated an internal force direction is opposite to its displacement.

> my textbook on electrostatic forces says that if a test charge is moved without changing the kinetic energy in a constant electric field then the work done according to work energy theorem is 0. then does that mean the change in potential energy is not equal to work done.

In this case the system is not the charges producing the uniform electric field and the test charge it is the test charge alone.
For the test charge alone the external forces are the forces exerted on it by the other charges (those producing the uniform electric field - often it is easier to just refer to the electric field) and the force that you exert on the charge.
If those two charges are equal and opposite (but not a Newton third law pair) then the net force on the test charge is zero.
So it is moves from one position to another along the direction of an electric field line then the net work done on the test charge is zero and hence by the work-energy theorem the change in kinetic energy will be zero.
You can think of it as the force on the test charge due to the other charges having a displacement in the direction of the force (positive work done) and the direction of the force that you exert of the charge as being opposite to the displacement of the charge (negative work done by the charge which is positive work done on you).
In terms of the test charges and other charges system the electric forces between the charges are internal forces (Newton third law pair) and you are the only external force.
The direction of the force that you apply on the test charge is opposite to the displacement of that charge so the external force does negative work.
The system of charges and the test charge started out with some electric potential energy and then ended up with less electric potential energy the difference being just the amount of negative work done **by** you or positive work done by the system **on** you.

So what you should do is at the start define a system.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a charged particle (no matter positive or negtive) moves from **a** to **b** along arbitrary trajectory (path independent).

The Kinetic energy (from the particle itself) and **potential energy** (**from the potential field**) of the particle at position **a** and **b** are $K_a,U_a$ and $K_b,U_b$ respectively. Based on energy conservation, we must have $$K_a+U_a=K_b+U_b$$
So the change of potential energy from **a** to **b** is
$$U_b-U_a=-(K_b-K_a)$$
Work energy theorem states that
$$(K_b-K_a)=q\int_a^b\vec{E}d\vec l$$
Thus, 
$$U_b-U_a=-q\int_a^b\vec{E}d\vec l$$
Clearly, the change in potential energy corresponds to the negtive work done by potential field.